# How can I speed up a rolling regression with multiple conditions in r?

Tags: r, regression, large-data, lm

I have a pretty big dataset (around 12 million rows) on which I need to run a rolling regression for every row which includes the entries of the past 30 rows. It's a simple linear regression but the regression needs to consider two factors: the stock and the time window on which it needs to run. I have figured out a way to run my 12 million regressions but unfortunately this way it takes way too long. lm() does too much work as I only need the intercept and the coefficients from the regression but with simpler linear regressions such as lmfit/lm.fit/lmList and so on  I have not been able to include my two conditions so far.
I have also tried to parallelise the regression but I have not been successful as I'm a beginner.
Can you help me speed up this calculation as much as possible?

Code:

```
regression <- df %>%
              rowwise() %>% 
              droplevels()%>%
              mutate(mod = list(lm(returns ~ Factor1 + Factor2 + Factor3 + Factor4,
                                   data = filter(df,
                                                 Stock == .env$Stock,
                                                 date <= .env$date,
                                                 date >= .env$datemonthbefore))))

regressionestimates <- regression %>%
  mutate(res = list(broom::tidy(mod)),
         broom::glance(mod)) %>% 
  select(date,
         Stock,
         res,
         nobs) %>% 
  unnest(res)
```

Comment: I find that `rowwise` makes everything very slow.  Maybe do one `Stock` at a time.  If the data is ordered by `date`, then use a for loop and to sequentially subset 30 consecutive rows.

Comment: @MichaelDewar Many thanks for your answer! So you would do two for loops nested, one for Stock and one for date? I have around 5000 Stocks to regress. So far my experiences with loops over large amounts of data have not been too good.

Comment: Yes.  I attempted an answer with two loops.  (`purrr::map` is implicitly a loop.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are faster ways to do this, but this works. (I think.)

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1000)

df <- tibble(date = rep(16001:19000, 5000),
             Stock = rep(1:5000, each = 3000)) %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date, origin = "1969-12-31"),
           returns = rnorm(15e6),
           Factor1 = rnorm(15e6),
           Factor2 = rnorm(15e6),
           Factor3 = rnorm(15e6),
           Factor4 = rnorm(15e6)) %>%
    nest(data = -Stock)

fit_one_stock <- function(data, window_size = 30L){
    data <- data %>% arrange(date)
    data.matrix <- as.matrix(data[,,drop = FALSE])
    steps <- nrow(data)-window_size

    output <- vector("list", steps+1)

    for(i in 0:steps){
        this_data <- data.matrix[(1+i):(window_size+i),,drop = FALSE]
        output[[i+1]]  <- coef(.lm.fit(cbind(1,this_data[,c("Factor1", "Factor2", "Factor3", "Factor4")]), this_data[,"returns"])) %>%
            setNames(c("(Intercept)", "Factor1", "Factor2", "Factor3", "Factor4"))
    }

    output

    bind_rows(output) %>%
        bind_cols(date = data[window_size:nrow(data),1])
}

tictoc::tic()
df2 <- df %>% #head(100) %>%
    mutate(models = map(data, fit_one_stock))
tictoc::toc()

df2 %>% select(-data) %>% unnest(models)
```

Comment: I came back to this after a while as it did not work out for me at first. Now I have found a way to run it but am still strugging with the unnesting part. Do you have any idea how I could unnest even when it's not efficient? 
"df3 <- df2 %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(data, models))" 
does not work for me as it says "Error: In row 1, can't recycle input of size 2015 to size 1890."

Comment: @ABCE, I have updated the answer.  I made a couple changes inside the function `fit_one_stock`.

Comment: The updated solution worked smoothly and didn't take too long for my dataset. Thank you!